# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null concerning a script in an echo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, echo

[image]I'm trying to change the color of a div on an `onclick` event.

Here is the error I'm getting:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null

Here is the code:

```
function changeSelection (newClick) {

        document.getElementById(newClick).style.backgroundColor="#4bc970";
        document.getElementById(newClick).style.color="#FFFFFF";
        if(oldClick!="" && document.getElementById(oldClick)!=null && oldClick != newClick){
            document.getElementById(oldClick).style.backgroundColor="#d2d2d2";
            document.getElementById(oldClick).style.color="#332836";
        }
        oldClick = newClick;
    }
```

The echo is found on another php page.

```
echo ("<tr><td><div class='courseDiv' onclick=changeSelection(".$classID.");><p class='textInsideLeftTable'>".$className. "</p><p class='arrow'>></p></div></td></tr>");
```

Any input will be appreciated.

More Code :

```
<?php
    require("connect.php");
    session_start();

    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN studentparent ON users.parentID = studentparent.parentID INNER JOIN studentsclasses ON studentparent.studentID = studentsclasses.studentID INNER JOIN classes ON classes.classID = studentsclasses.classID WHERE users.parentID=:parentID');
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':parentID' => $_SESSION['parentID']
    )) or die(var_dump($stmt->errorInfo()));

    $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $className = $row['classCode'];
        $classID = $row['classID'];
        echo ("<tr><td><div class='courseDiv' onclick=\"changeSelection('".$classID."');\"><p class='textInsideLeftTable'>".$className. "</p><p class='arrow'>></p></div></td></tr>"); 
    }
?>
```

ANSWER :
I inversed the "" with ''. Also, I forgot to give it the div id. I was trying to change the value and not the div value.
I hope it makes sens.

```
echo ('<tr><td><div id="div_'. $classID .'"onclick="changeSelection(\'div_'.$classID.'\');" class="courseDiv"><p class="textInsideLeftTable">'.$className. '</p><p class="arrow">></p></div></td></tr>');
```

Comment: Have you checked that the value for $classID is correct and that you have exactly one element in your html structure with that id and that the javascript is only triggered when the page has loaded all the required dom elements?

Comment: Yes I have. If I get out the on click event and put it right after the > that closes the class courseDiv, it shows me the right id for each div (html format). I believe it's a syntax error that i'm not able to find.

Comment: Please show us the page after PHP generates the div.

Comment: I have added a picture to the original post. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add single quotes around it, so that JavaScript will treat it as a string instead of a variable.

```
changeSelection('".$classID."')
```

Comment: Thank you. I've made that modification but still get the same error.

echo ("<tr><td><div class='courseDiv' onclick=changeSelection('".$classID."');><p class='textInsideLeftTable'>".$className. "</p><p class='arrow'>></p></div></td></tr>");

Comment: Oh, maybe another thing that might cause trouble: the whole thing should be in brackets too. Like onclick=\"changeSelection(".$classID.");\"

Comment: Sadly it still didn't fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById(newClick) gives you null means that the id passed as newClick doesn't exists or it is not found in the current context.

add statement console.log(newClick); to your changeSelection() on the first line. And check console(F12 developer tools) to see whats the value being passed.

Comment: If it prints the correct id, it means the element with the id doesn't exist in the document. Please check if the element exists.

Comment: I have done an echo of classID and it also gives me the same value

Comment: What is oldClick? where is it defined? where does it get value from?
Also check which line in the function gives you the error.

Comment: at the top of my page. <script > var oldClick ="";</script>

Comment: which line do you get error on? you will find this in the console(F12 developer tools)

Comment: document.getElementById(newClick).style.backgroundColor="#4bc970"; It underlines .style.backgroundColor="#4bc970";

Comment: Ok. where is the element with the id in variable classID? can you show the html for the elements? And also show the value of classID after it is echoed.

Comment: <?php
require("connect.php");
session_start();
  $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users INNER JOIN studentparent ON users.parentID = studentparent.parentID INNER JOIN studentsclasses ON studentparent.studentID = studentsclasses.studentID INNER JOIN classes ON classes.classID = studentsclasses.classID WHERE users.parentID=:parentID');
    $stmt->execute(array(
     ':parentID' => $_SESSION['parentID']
     )) or die(var_dump($stmt->errorInfo()));

Comment: $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
  foreach ($result as $row) {
  $className = $row['classCode'];
  $classID = $row['classID'];
  echo ("<tr><td><div class='courseDiv' onclick=\"changeSelection('".$classID."');\"><p class='textInsideLeftTable'>".$className. "</p><p class='arrow'>></p></div></td></tr>"); 
 }
?>

Comment: I'll add the code to the initial post. it'll be easier to read

Comment: Ok. Are you sure there is an element in your html with the attribute "id" equal to the value in the classID variable ?

Comment: yes, I added an echo before I have the div classID. I have added a picture to the original post.

Comment: Lets say classID contains value "1". So is there any element in your html which is like 
"<div id="1" ></div>" or any element other than div having id="1" ?

Comment: no. The parameter I pass in the echo div... is unique and the function does receive the value. I'm thinking it's more of a syntax error in the echo

Comment: I got it to work thank you for your time! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

So My knowledge of PHP is pretty limited but as far as i remember, shouldn't you use

```
changeSelection('"$classID"')
```

instead of

```
changeSelection('".$classID."')
```

**why are there two dots before and after the $classId**, if you have stored Id of your div tag, in a variable called classId all you need is $classId to get its value and document.getElementById("classId_value") should return you the element.

Comment: I took to consideration what you said. I have tried and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Are you storing the value of an ID attribute inside the classId variable?? or is it value of CLASS attribute.. eg.
<div id='div_id' class='div_class'>text_random</div>

then classId should contain "div_id" and not "div_class" as value

Comment: inside the classID variable. I don't really understand what you mean in the second part of your answer.

Comment: as an example, if your div looks like this...
<div id='div_id' class='div_class'>text_random</div>
$classID = "div_id" is correct. your code will work.

$classID = "div_class" is wrong. your code will not work

Comment: from what I understood, this is what you wanted me to try out : echo ("<tr><td><div class='courseDiv' onclick=\"changeSelection("'$classID'");\"><p class='textInsideLeftTable'>".$className. "</p><p class='arrow'>></p></div></td></tr>");  It didn't work. I also tried it with the .$classID.

Comment: Ok no, this is not what i meant. I am sorry can't help you.

Comment: Thank you for trying. I really appreciate it :)